# I've just cloned a GitHub and some (but not all) files are considered modified even though IDE says they are identical to repository version. Why?

Tags: git, diff

I've just cloned the GitHub repository at https://github.com/aic-sri-international/aic-util , and some (but not all) files are considered modified by both the IntelliJ IDEA IDE and `git status`.

There are 549 Java files total in the repository and 49 are indicated as modified by `git status`. I don't see any obvious pattern in which files are considered modified and which are not.

A diff on IntelliJ IDEA says files' "contents are identical" to repository's.

Even after using `git restore` for a file, it still shows as modified!

A `git diff` shows something like this:

```
@@ -1,67 +1,67 @@
-Line 1
-Line 2
...
-Line 67
+Line 1
+Line 2
...
+Line 67
```

I wondered if this could be due to `CRLF`/`LF` differences. I'm on macOS and the original project was developed on Windows. However, using `cat -ve` shows both modified and non-modified files using `CRLF`.

What explains this?

**Edit; short solution:** the chosen answer is very detailed but getting a solution out of it takes careful and long reading.

Essentially, for some reason the repository is storing `CRLF` files even though it should contain `LF` files. Simply adding the modified files with `git add . --renormalize` with a recent version of Git (equal to or above 2.16)  and committing them should create a new commit in the repository with the correct LF format.

Comment: open in macOS with vim. then try `:set fileformat=unix`  and save before git status

Comment: What is the repository you cloned?

Comment: @torek It's https://github.com/aic-sri-international/aic-util

Comment: @user118967: Important information like this belongs into the question, not into a comment. I took the liberty of editing it in for you :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

The files *in the repository* are "bad" (in some sense).  The problem would go away if whoever owns the repository would "fix" (in some sense) the committed files.

## Long

The key to understanding this problem lies in cloning the actual repository and visiting the commit(s) in question.  The repository—as noted in a comment—is https://github.com/aic-sri-international/aic-util, and a problematic commit, perhaps the one you were looking at, is `60fa84abe4357b4fc0acb3d18cefc5b3c40958b6` (their `master` at the time I am writing this).

In this commit, we have a `.gitattributes` file consisting of these two lines:

```
* text=auto
*.java text eol=crlf
```

We also—this is crucial—have *blob objects* stored in the repository with literal CRLF line endings.  For instance, object `97d1f597b409bdd68ad21d98495f85a40e199cbf` is a blob and holds this commit's version of `src/main/java/com/sri/ai/util/AICUtilConfiguration.java`, and—as `vis`<sup>1</sup> shows us—it contains:

```
$ git cat-file -p 97d1f597b409bdd68ad21d98495f85a40e199cbf | head | vis
/*\^M
 * Copyright (c) 2013, SRI International\^M
 * All rights reserved.\^M
 * Licensed under the The BSD 3-Clause License;\^M
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.\^M
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:\^M
 * \^M
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause\^M
 * \^M
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without\^M
```

#### What does this mean?

This means the *committed file* contains CRLF line endings.

No *committed file* can ever be changed.  Commit `60fa84abe4357b4fc0acb3d18cefc5b3c40958b6` contains *this version* of *this file*, with CRLF line endings.  That will be true forever.  No one anywhere can do anything about this.

#### OK, but then why does `git status` say it's "modified"?

This may depend at least slightly on your Git vintage, but mine does say this, just as the OP asked:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with `origin/master`

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   src/main/java/com/sri/ai/util/AICUtilConfiguration.java
[many more, snipped]
```

> I wondered if this could be due to CRLF/LF differences

Yes.

The `*.java text eol=crlf` line in the `.gitattributes` file amounts to two sets of instructions to Git:

1. When copying this file *from* a commit to my working tree (`git restore`) or *from* Git's index to my working tree (`git checkout`, `git switch`, most other such commands), *change any LF-only line endings to CRLF line endings.*

There's nothing wrong with this instruction, but since every line in the file inside the commit—stored in the form of the blob object—already has CRLF line endings, this instruction does not *do* anything.

2. When copying this file from my working tree into Git's index (so that any updates I make to it are now prepared to be committed), *change any CRLF line endings to LF-only line endings.*

If I *don't* run `git add` on file `src/main/java/com/sri/ai/util/AICUtilConfiguration.java`, Git won't update the index copy.  So the index copy—which currently still has the CRLF line endings—will go into any *new* commit I make, perpetuating the oddity that the *committed* copy has CRLF line endings.

If I *do* run `git add`, Git *might or might not* actually update the file, depending on Git vintage and other details.  The problem here is that Git tries to be very clever.  If I change the working tree copy for real—e.g., add a comment to it or something—then `git add` really does have to re-compress and re-Git-ify this updated working tree copy, and stuff that updated copy into Git's index.  This will obey instruction #2 above and therefore turn all the CRLFs into LF-only.

If I then commit using this version of the file, the file will have LF-only line endings *in the commit*, in its Git-ified object form.  We'll be one file down, out of the 49 (your count) or 129 (my count) `.java` files.

We won't *see* this change (to replace CRLF with LF) later, if we `git checkout` or `git switch`-to the new commit, because the files we *see*, in our working tree, obey rule #1.  But this file will no longer show up as "modified" because Git knows that rule #2 takes the CRLF-s back out, turning the file back an into LF-only file in Git's index.  That is, our working tree, index, and `HEAD` commit will all be in harmony.

In some versions of Git, Git's "smartness" here is too clever, and if we *don't* touch the files in any way, `git add` won't fix the files.  However, if we have `git add --renormalize` (Git 2.16 or later), we can use that to fix the files.  Or, in the version of Git I have on the machine I am testing this on (Git 2.27.0, a bit behind the most recent version, but well past 2.16), a simple `git add .` suffices, even without `--renormalize`.

#### More about Git version dependence

The code to handle line-ending conversions in Git has been a bit weird—and perhaps the word "fragile" is even appropriate—over the years.  Various problems popped up in Git versions 1.7 and 1.8, some of the attributes were broken for a while with a fix in Git 2.10, and so on.  So not every version of Git behaves the way a modern (2.27, 2.30, whatever) Git does.

There are also non-Git programs (such as Eclipse with its internal [JGit libraries](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)) that read and write Git repositories.  These don't necessarily work "right" from Git's point of view.  They are *supposed* to be compatible, but given that Git itself got CRLF conversion "wrong" now and then, who could complain if JGit doesn't quite do the same thing as Git?  Perhaps the problem is not a specific *Git* version, but a specific *something-else* version.

#### Aside: what if I hate CRLF line endings?

If the repository itself adds new commits that fix the internal files so that they have LF-only line endings, but keeps the `.gitattributes` directives to use CRLF line endings in your working tree copies, you'll always see CRLF line endings in your working tree, in any fresh clone or checkout.  If you don't like this—e.g., if you're on a Mac or on Linux and don't want to, e.g., have vim use its magic "fileformat" detection to hide the CRLF line endings from you, there is a simple workaround.  You can create, in your clone, a `.git/info/attributes` file.  In that file, you can write `*.java text eol=lf`.  This line overrides the `.gitattributes` line, so that Git will use, as its two rules:

- on check out: use LF-only, i.e., don't add CRs to LFs (but don't strip CRs either)
- on `git add`: convert CRLF to LF-only

It's annoying to have to do this after a new clone, but it's easy enough to set up.  Note though that `.git/info/attributes` is *not* a *committed* file, and is not in your working tree, so Git never updates it, regardless of which commit you check out.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `vis` command turns <kbd>control-M</kbd> characters into `\^M` to make them visible here; this command exists on macOS and other BSD-based or BSD-derived systems.  `vis` has the ability to encode text for transmission across various devices that might otherwise destroy some encodings or render them invisible (you can of course also do this with atob or uuencode, but those are not human-readable at all).

If you have `cat -v`, that also turns <kbd>control-M</kbd> visible, but not in a perfectly invertible manner: a text file that contains the literal character sequence <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> becomes indistinguishable from one that contains a control-M.  Try, e.g., `printf 'foo^Mbar\r\n' | cat -v` vs `printf 'foo\\^Mbar\r\n' | vis` to see why `vis` is superior:

```
sh-3.2$ printf 'foo^Mbar\r\n' | cat -v
foo^Mbar^M
sh-3.2$ printf 'foo\\^Mbar\r\n' | vis
foo\134^Mbar\^M
```

Note that `vis` has many flags to control its output encoding, and not all encodings are fully invertible—but the default output *is*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I the OP am also the repo's owner. My understanding is that I must use `git add .` with a recent git version to fix the repo. Sounds good. But I would also like to know what incorrect step led to this, which was, as I understand, storing those java files as blobs. How might that have happened? I certainly don't remember doing that on purpose.

Comment: All files in Git are stored as blobs. Whatever software you've been using has been storing them as blobs with CRLF line endings. Old Git software (versions before 2.something) might do that too because the way that line-ending manipulation is described (via `.gitattributes`) changed over the years. If your Git is at least 2.16 and you use it directly, `git add --renormalize .` is supposed to fix it all. I'm not sure whether the behavior I saw with my Git is *required* of Git now, or if you still need the `--renormalize` officially.